# C++ Random Generating distinct numbers problem

Tags: c++

I'm struggling with the rand() module in c++ to list numbers from 10 to 100 as distinct from each other, but I shouldn't use vectors to solve this problem. I tried to achieve this with loop and if structure, but I can suppress the same element in the array even if I don't encounter the same numbers when comparing two arrays. When I compare 22 and 12 I get true but I can compare 22 with 44 again and the program will still return true. That's why I couldn't solve the problem.

I am not getting algorithmically correct result on this code. How can I solve this simply without vector methods?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime> 
int main()
{
    int dizi1[10], dizi2[10];
    srand (time(0));
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
    dizi1[i] = rand() %91 + 10;
    dizi2[i] = rand() % 91 + 10;
    if(dizi1[i]!=dizi2[i])
    {
    std::cout<<dizi1[i]<<", ";
    }
    else
    {
        dizi2[i]= rand()%91 +10;
        std::cout<<dizi2[i]<< " ,";
    }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *How can I solve this simply without vector methods?* -- Generating random numbers in C++ has [nothing to do with vectors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution).

Comment: Have you looked at C++'s [<random>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) header? There is [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) that you can specify to return numbers between 10 and 100. Your current approach is still quire "C" like.

Comment: Consider shuffling the number from 10-100 and picking the first 2x10. Or is that what you mean by "using vectors"?

Comment: @Yunnosch You mean using [std::shuffle](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/shuffle)

Comment: *but I shouldn't use vectors to solve this problem* -- What about `std::deque`?  What about `std::set`?

Comment: @PepijnKramer Something like that. It is usually the method for "from 10 to 100 as distinct from each other", isn't it?

Comment: @Paul Mckenzie  I have seen vector defined when using random_shuffle method. So I was looking for a solution other than this way.

Comment: @AnkaHanım -- You don't need vector to use `random_shuffle` or `std::shuffle`.  A regular array of `int` can be used.  Basically, the solution is a two line program with `std::iota` and `std::random_shuffle`.

Comment: Using C++ and not using std::vector, why the limitation?

Comment: Anka, I think I got it. Shuffling requires something like a vector (though there are alternativesd) and you mustn't. I recommend to [edit] and state that clearly. I think it means that you are almost explicitly forbidden to use shuffling. If your goal is to solve with loops until distinct (NOT the usual, efficient method I think) you need to specifcy that. It will however include checking against already selected members of `dizi` I think. Maybe you need to specificy whether only `dizi1[i]` dizi2[i]` need to be different (your code looks like that, or whether all `diziN[any]` need to be.

Comment: @Paul Mckenzie I am still very new to C++ language. So I'm trying to trade from the basics. I'll look into the method you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: Do not want post full explanation so posting code as a comment: https://godbolt.org/z/E39MafdYP

Comment: @Yunnosch so what should i look for to avoid repeated digits inside the array?

Comment: @Marek R thank you so much. I'm understand that.

Comment: I think I do not get what you mean by the question, because the answer seems so obviously "for repeated numbers in the array" ("numbers" I am convinced, not "digits"). For which you would have to loop repeatedly over the array(s). By the way, you should [edit] and provide more info. E.g. what needs to be different, some examples of OK solutions, some examples of non-OK solutions, especially highlighted some examples which your current code produces not OK and some it produces OK. Each with a highlight of why the not-OK examples are not OK. That will by the way help you to learn debugging.

Comment: To be clear, in my previous comment I refer to the question in your comment to me, not the question at the top of this page - could be unclear or confusing. Sorry.

Comment: Yes, the shown approach is fundamentally flawed, and a completely different approach is required in order to accomplish the given task: generate all numbers in the range, consecutively, place them in the array, then use `rand()` to shuffle the array. Mission accomplished.

Comment: @Yunnosch Actually, I understand what you mean. What I want to do is that the randomly generated numbers in a sequence are different from each other in the same sequence. I can exemplify such a situation as 1 1 3 4 6 does not happen. I realize that even if I do this with loops, it won't make much sense.

Comment: @AnkaHanım -- I'm still trying to figure out why you insist on using loops for this.  Your attempt is like trying to learn to walk by standing on your toes.  [The solution is as simple as this](https://godbolt.org/z/zrv8bsfa3).  If you were to get this question on an interview, and you started to write loops to fill in the random numbers and checking for duplicates, that would not make a good impression on the interviewer.

Comment: @Paul McKenzie I'll try the methods you suggested outside of the loop. I realized it wouldn't be this way

Comment: @AnkaHanım What is considered basic has changed. A lot of the teraching material out there is still very "C" oriented (even after 30+ years). std::vector is NOT an advanced topic now, it is a very basic one (like std::string). In fact the "C" style arrays are much more likely to give you problems due to bugs.

Comment: `int dizi1[10]` is advanced.  `std::vector<int> dizi1(10)` is basic.

Comment: Side note: [rand() Considered Harmful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/events/goingnative-2013/rand-considered-harmful)

Answer (score 0):

Using std::vector (or std::array) is recommended, just forget "C" style arrays.

```
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

// learn to build (small) functions
// with only one effect
auto initialize_values()
{
    std::vector<int> values;
    for (int i = 10; i < 100; ++i) values.push_back(i);
    return values;
}

void print_first_ten_values(const std::vector<int>& values)
{
    // now pick the first 10
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << values[i] << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 random(rd());

    auto values = initialize_values(); // just an array from 10..100
    
    // by shuffling all values stay unique
    std::shuffle(values.begin(), values.end(), random);

    print_first_ten_values(values);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @pepjin kramer std::mt19937Is this coming from an internal library or is it a module I'm not familiar with? And thank you. Now I'm understand.

Comment: It is from C++'s random library, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine

Comment: about initialize_values, I showed this function because with "C" style arrays returning an array involves returning a double raw pointer (all size information is lost and who has to delete the memory is always unclear). A std::vector solves all these problems for you. That's why we say it is a less advanced concept ;)

Comment: What's that `initialize_values()` doing that `std::iota()` couldn't?  And why does `print_first_ten_values()` need that C-style loop instead of `for (auto i: values | std::views::take(10))`?

Comment: Toby I agree with your comments. Didn't want to throw too much new stuff in for OP